# labelling button in before checkout process

Tags: e-commerce, labels, checkout

I read that each label, especially in ecommerce websites, indicates what users have to do in the next steps, so, terms like *continue* or something like that, must be avoided. I'm working on a site to order food which is made of 4 steps:

1. choose something to eat
2. login/register
3. choose delivery hours
4. confirm

Each of these steps is in a separate page. The first one, is a page of a restaurant that has some menus or dishes. Users can choose what they want to eat and then proceed to the next step (give personal data - or login). Due to technical reason I can't put the 3rd step (choose delivery hours) before the 2nd one.

The problem is, in the restaurant page (1st step), to proceed to the next steps I put a button labelled "*go to checkout*", but I saw that some people ask me, where can I choose delivery hours?

I thought to change the label to "*choose delivery hours*", but after clicking on it, users are brought on the login/register page. This can be seen as a consistency problem (I told you that you can choose delivery hours, but first I ask you to register or login). What do you think about it? What label do you suggest?

Comment: I would try and combine the login and delivery pages, maybe grey out the delivery section or have a pop over with the login.

Answer (score 1):

I assume the ordering food as a service for direct consumption rather than buying ingredients. If this is the case, I think that overall process can be clustered as;

- Defining the order (selecting meal and delivery hours, extra sauces etc..)
- Completing the order

While user is defining the order, the delivery hour can have influence on the selection of the user. They can be connected in the overall flow.

Completing an order can be expanded to payment and confirmation. You can add different methods of payment in this page.

So i will use two short name for buttons. While defining the order - checkout, for completing the order - confirm. I hope that it helps.

Comment: Thank you, but as I wrote, I can't put the choice of delivery hours in the same page of the choice of the lunch. This because, at this time, if someone choose a delivery hour too close to the actual hour, they will have an error, because a restaurant requires some time to prepare the lunch (f.e. if you want your lunch delivered at 13.20 and you start ordering at 13.10, you won't have it, because restaurant requires 10 minutes since it receives the order, to prepare it). So delivery hours is the last step (except confirm step). In this way, how can I label the button?

Comment: Understand. You can force user to select something 20 min. from the current time but these discussions are very depended on the problem itself. Rather than focusing on these areas, I think that checkout will work fine. Selecting delivery hour and the address has a related bind for completing an order. If you are going to create a separate section and name it "order details" - that may also work fine.

Answer (score 1):

The important thing here is to keep the user informed; your users are complaining because they don't understand the process, and it is surprising them.

Instead of relying on button labels to let them know what happens next, you could use a progress tracker design to show them the entire process, and their current place:

[image: Progress Tracker mockup]

Answer (score 0):

If technical reasons prevent you from having an optimal flow for the user, just add a simple line of text to your Sign Up page: 'You can choose delivery hours in the next step'.